# Can't get rid of fixed horizontal scroll on iframe in Firefox

Tags: html, css, iframe, widget, horizontal-scrolling

Creating a widget for my site. Check it out at http://bit.ly/w42SC4.

Looks good in Chrome and IE. However, I'm getting this ugly fixed horizontal scroll in Firefox. I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
<iframe src="http://www.coupongravy.com/vipiframe.php"
scrolling="yes"
width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" noresize="" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" hspace="0"
vspace="0" style="overflow-x: hidden; border:1px solid #ef6ea8;width:300px;height:250px;"></iframe>
```

I added an `overflow-x: hidden` to your style.

Tested on Firefox 8.0.